# Configure TOMCAT in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have by default TOMCAT installed in my system which I can start/stop from terminal using:

```bsh
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
```

But unfortunately I can't configure the same in Eclipse.

I have tried all possibilities of directing the **Apache Tomcat v7.0** in the **Tomcat Installation directory (*Window→Preferences→Server→Runtime Environment→Add→Tomcat7*)** but still getting this notification: ***"Unknown version of Tomcat was specified."***

Can anyone help me with Tomcat configuration for Eclipse (without re-installing another server).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat and Eclipse Integration Error : "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435283/tomcat-and-eclipse-integration-error-unknown-version-of-tomcat-was-specified)

Answer (score 3):

Even though its late, I'm posting this for future readers. I found out there is an easy way of doing that. You can follow this blog post which is providing a step by step guide to do it: [Install Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu.html)

**Step 1:**
Open the Eclipse.

**Step 2:**
Goto Windows → Preferences in the menu bar and select the Runtime Environments under the Server.

[image]

**Step 3:**
Click on the 'Add' button.

**Step 4:**
Select your Apache Tomcat version under the 'Apache' root and click 'Next'.

[image]

**Step 5:**
Browse and select the Tomcat installation directory.

[image]

**Step 6:**
Click on the 'Finish' button

**Step 7:**
Click on the 'OK' button to close the Preferences dialog.

[image]

Comment: When providing an external link with a solution, keep in mind that links may become unavailable. Thus it is preferable to include a short description of what's involved in the solution.  This way your answer will remain helpful and relevant even if the referenced site "dies."

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying tomcat source directory but it needs to specify tomcat binary installation root directory, also known as CATALINA_HOME.

You can download apache-tomcat and untar it there or add a links.

If you untar apache-tomcat in /opt/apache-tomcat-7 you can create symbolic links to its folders.

```
/etc/tomcat/tomcat7$ ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-7/conf conf
/etc/tomcat/tomcat7$ ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-7/lib lib
/etc/tomcat/tomcat7$ ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-7/logs logs
/etc/tomcat/tomcat7$ ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps webapps
/etc/tomcat/tomcat7$ ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-7/work work
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, the application doesn't have default permission to read/edit all the folders.

Change the permission for tomcat to 755 and it will work.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/
```