# Tomcat and Eclipse Integration Error: "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified."

Tags: 13.10, java, eclipse, tomcat7

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and gnome 3.10.

I have followed this tutorial to set up tomcat and eclipse.:

[Set up Eclipse and Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.10 to create Java RESTful Web Services with Jersey](http://gridlab.dimes.unical.it/lackovic/eclipse-tomcat-ubuntu-jersey/)

But when I reach **step 9**, I get the following error on eclipse:

[image: Unknown version of Tomcat was specified]

I tried many solutions I saw here on Ask Ubuntu but none worked for me.

I have checked the usr/local folder but tomcat7 is not there.

I checked the `/usr/share` folder and tomcat7 is there.

[image: tomcat location]

I used the following command to install eclipse and tomcat:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse tomcat7 -y
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest installing standalone Tomcat into `/usr/local` instead of using the one in `/usr/share` directory.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://apache-mirror.rbc.ru/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.52/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.52.tar.gz
tar -xzf apache-tomcat-7.0.52.tar.gz
sudo mv apache-tomcat7.0.52 /usr/local/apache-tomcat7.0.52
```

Then use `/usr/local/apache-tomcat7.0.52`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I updated the text and I have added the /usr/local folder content. as you can see the tomcat is not there but it is located in /usr/share/

Comment: It's still the same. I have added a new screenshot.

Comment: where from did you get this Tomcat?

Comment: This is how I installed eclipse and tomcat: sudo apt-get install eclipse tomcat7 -y         I have followed the steps in the tutorial.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake. Move `tomcat7` directory back.

Comment: Already done :)

Comment: Use updated instructions

Comment: Thanks.. I used sudo apt-get purge tomcat7 to remove the previous tomcat and then I followed your instructions and now it's working like a charm :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the Tomcat folder you're pointing to contains the following files:

```
conf/catalina.policy
conf/server.xml
conf/web.xml
conf/context.xml
conf/tomcat-users.xml
conf/catalina.policy
conf/catalina.properties
lib/catalina.jar
```

as Eclipse is scanning for them.

[image: Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost in Eclipse]

Here is a Linux command which can help you to find that folder:

```
find /opt /usr '(' -name catalina.policy -o -name tomcat-users.xml -o -name catalina.properties ')' -exec sh -c 'dirname $(dirname {})' ';' | uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu the application doesn't have default permission to read/edit all the folders.

I realized that the permissions for the TOMCAT installation directory were not set correctly.

I changed it to 755 and it worked.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your server in any directory, just that the Apache Tomcat directory has read access by its user.

Example: `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache-tomcat7.0.52`